# how to set up readonly property in excel vba class module

Tags: class, excel, vba

I have the following in a class module called `clsAgent`:

```
Option Explicit
Const AgentEmailCol = 9
Private pAgentSheetName As String
Private pIDRange As Range
Private pAgentID As String
Private pAgentEmail As String

Public Property Get AgentSheetName() As String
    AgentSheetName = pAgentSheetName
End Property

Public Property Let AgentSheetName(AgentSheetName As String)
    pAgentSheetName = AgentSheetName
End Property

Public Property Get IDRange() As Range
    Set IDRange = pIDRange
End Property

Public Property Set IDRange(IDRange As Range)
    Set pIDRange = IDRange
End Property

Public Property Get AgentID() As String
    AgentID = pAgentID
End Property

Public Property Let AgentID(AgentID As String)
    pAgentID = AgentID
End Property


Public Property Get AgentEmail() As String
    AgentEmail = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.AgentID, Me.IDRange, AgentEmailCol, False)
End Property
```

in a class called `clsWorkingRange` I have:

```
Option Explicit

Private pSheetName As String
Private pColNum As Integer
Private pTargetRange As Range

Public Property Get SheetName() As String
    SheetName = pSheetName
End Property

Public Property Let SheetName(SheetName As String)
    pSheetName = SheetName
End Property


Public Property Get ColNum() As Integer
    ColNum = pColNum
End Property

Public Property Let ColNum(ColNum As Integer)
    pColNum = ColNum
End Property


Public Property Get TargetRange() As Range
    Set TargetRange = pTargetRange
End Property

Public Property Set TargetRange(TargetRange As Range)
    Set pTargetRange = TargetRange
End Property


Private Function Get_Rows_Generic(work_sheet_get As String, column_num As Integer)
'worksheet is the name of a sheet in the form of a string
    Dim ws As Worksheet:             Set ws = Worksheets(work_sheet_get)
    Dim rows_count As Long:        rows_count = ws.Cells(rows.Count, column_num).End(xlUp).Row
    Get_Rows_Generic = rows_count
End Function

Public Function set_range(sheet_name As String, col1 As Integer) As Range
'   returns the range of a given column using all the rows in a street
    Dim rows1 As Long
    rows1 = Get_Rows_Generic(sheet_name, 1)
    Dim range1 As Range ' range of first search
    With Worksheets(sheet_name)
        Set range1 = .Range(.Cells(1, col1), .Cells(rows1, col1)) ' set the range being searched first
    End With

    Set set_range = range1
End Function
```

I have a class called `clsWorkingSheet`:

```
Option Explicit

Private pSheetName As String
Private pSheet As Worksheet

Public Property Get SheetName() As String
    SheetName = pSheetName
End Property

Public Property Let SheetName(SheetName As String)
    pSheetName = SheetName
End Property

Public Property Get Sheet() As Worksheet
    Set Sheet = pSheet
End Property

Public Property Set Sheet(Sheet As Worksheet)
    Set pSheet = Sheet
End Property
```

In a separate module I have the following:

```
Sub test_agent_class()

Dim agent_Sheet As clsWorkingSheet
Set agent_Sheet = New clsWorkingSheet

agent_Sheet.SheetName = "agentsFullOutput.csv"
Set agent_Sheet.Sheet = Worksheets(agent_Sheet.SheetName)

Dim agent_Range As clsWorkingRange
Set agent_Range = New clsWorkingRange

Set agent_Range.TargetRange = agent_Range.set_range(agent_Sheet.SheetName, 1)

Dim agent_Individual As clsAgent
Set agent_Individual = New clsAgent

Set agent_Individual.IDRange = agent_Range.TargetRange
        Debug.Print agent_Individual.IDRange.Address

agent_Individual.AgentID = "ObjectID(52d56512763f4a1c608b4753)"
        Debug.Print agent_Individual.AgentID
        Debug.Print agent_Individual.AgentEmail

end sub
```

I get the following error: `Run-time error '1004': Method 'AgentEmail' of object 'clsAgent' failed`

¸

Comment: You didn't set `IDRange`

Comment: @TimWilliams I made the change and now get a different error. I edited the question to account for your comment.

Comment: @JNevill In my Locals widow I see     `: AgentEmail : <Method 'VLookup' of object 'WorksheetFunction' failed> : String`

Comment: now i'm thinking the IDRange needs to include the worksheet??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything here looks fine to me. I've tested it myself and it worked as I believe you expect it should.

The only thing I see going wrong is if your `agent_Range.TargetRange` has less than 9 columns, since that's what you are looking up in your vlookup with `Const AgentEmailCol = 9`

### Based on your updated question/code:

It looks like this bit in your `clsWorkingRange.set_range()` function only returns a range with a single column. You can't do a `vlookup` that fetches from the 9th column in a 1 column sized range. You'll need to make sure that agent_Range.TargetRange is set to something that is at least 9 columns wide. Check the output of your `Debug.Print agent_Individual.IDRange.Address` to confirm.

Comment: I'm still getting an error.  I'm wondering if IDRange isn't specific enough.  ie. do I need to somehow include the worksheet?

Comment: What is the range? Is the range in the same workbook? If not, is the range in a workbook that is open?

Comment: Updated with some thoughts

Comment: that's a good call.  I'll go look at everything.  I think i need a class property for vlookp range.

Comment: The IDRange was for just one column where I needed the whole sheet.  I added a search range property and the whole think worked fine.  Thanks again!